# Finding the factorial of odd number from the input value in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input;
    int result = 1;
    
    printf("Enter the integer number : ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("n:!\n\n");
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= input; i = i + 2)
    {   
        for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
        {
            result *= k;
        }
        printf("%d:%d\n", i, result);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have created such code to determine the factorial of input's odd number. During the testing, I have found out that beyond the factorial of 5, the value gets wrong. Seems like the calculation is going wrong but I don't know what is the problem in my code.

Comment: The outer loop needs to be initialized `result=1`

Comment: Your inner loop is repeating the entire calculation each time, probably you wanted to continue where you left off in the previous iteration?

Comment: `int` is a signed type, and most commonly using 32 bits of storage. That means it can have values from around minus two billion to plus two billion. Arithmetic overflow (doing arithmetic that pushes the value above the max possible value) of a signed integer leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @ZhuSong you mean between the first and the second for loop right? was it because the previous result accumulated?

Comment: @JungJaeWon The result of the last time is multiplied by the result of this time.

Comment: To be clear, if `input` is 7, your expected output should be `1 6 120 5040`, is it right?

Comment: If you want to use the previous result, you can try this `for (int i = 3; i <= input; i = i + 2)
    {
        for (int k = i - 1; k <= i; k++)
        {
            result *= k;
        }
        printf("%d:%d\n", i, result);
    }` .

Answer (score 2):

your problem is you are multiplying result with the old value it has in each inner loop. to solve this before the start of inner loop reset result to 1 by :

> result = 1;

and this is not related to the question but I prefer to avoid this algorithm as it is O(n^2 /2) we can consider it O(n^2), rather you can use this one it is O(n) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int input;
long double result = 1;

printf("Enter the integer number : ");
scanf("%d", &input);
printf("n:!\n\n");

for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
{   
    result *= i;
    if(i%2==1){ printf("%d:%Le\n", i, result); } //note that im using %Le for long double type
}
```

also be careful with ***int*** type you are using for result, int is limited you should use ***long double*** because fact operation's result will be big

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's probably best not to use scanf for ill defined data such as user input. In fact, the rule "don't use scanf" very often valid. A program such as this might be better off using a command line argument instead.

Technically in C main should be `int main(void)` or some variation of `int main(int argc, char *argv[]`.

As others have mentioned, it would be more reasonable to use unsigned integers for a calculation like this where negative numbers are impossible. For something like a factorial it would make sense to use a larger integer type too.

Anyway, on topic: why don't you do it more simply? The factorial function can be iterated in one loop. If you only want to print the result when `i` is odd, just check whether it's odd.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static unsigned get_input(void);
static unsigned interpret_string(const char *str);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned input;
    uint64_t result = 1;

    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Enter the integer number : ");
        input = get_input();
        putchar('\n');
    } else {
        input = interpret_string(argv[1]);
    }

    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= input; ++i) {
        result *= i;
        if (i & 1)
            printf("%-2d = %"PRIu64"\n", (int)i, result);
    }

    return 0;
}

static unsigned
interpret_string(const char *str)
{
    char    *endp = NULL;
    unsigned ret  = strtoll(str, &endp, 10);
    
    if (endp == str) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input \"%s\"\n", str);
        exit(1);
    }

    return ret;
}

static unsigned
get_input(void)
{
    char buf[1024];
    fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
    return interpret_string(buf);
}
```